# Force Thunderbird XPI Add-on install (fails)

Tags: installation, thunderbird, browser-addons

I am trying to install an extension (directly from hard disk) into Thunderbird 31. However, Thunderbird simply does nothing when I drag the *.xpi file to Thunderbird's Add-ons Manager window. There is not even a message saying that the add-on is incompatible, or something.

I have already edited install.rdf which now includes the following:

```
  <em:targetApplication>
      <!-- Thunderbird -->
      <Description em:id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}"
         em:minVersion="17.0"
         em:maxVersion="31.*" />
   </em:targetApplication>
```

Still no reaction of Thunderbird when trying to install this Add-on.

What else that is contained in an Add-on's *.xpi file could prevent Thunderbird from accepting it?

Thanks for any hints.

Regards David.P

Comment: Is it the same if you select "Install Addon from file..." in the toolbox-icon top-right?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being late, I was not notified of your answer. Actually this has been solved, see here: 

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2878439&p=13811501#p13811501

Comment: It would be appreciated, if you document your solution here too in an answer to your own question below. Just copy the main findings from your other posts here in a separate answer. This is how superuser works and how superuser grows to a tool for documenting your problems and the belonging solutions